# Python subprocess running ssh -f localhost getting stuck on reading from stdout

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

The below command keeps on getting stuck whereas I expected the control to return back because I am doing ssh in background mode

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE
p = run(['ssh', '-f', 'localhost', 'sleep', '1000'], stdout=PIPE)
```

Can someone help me understand where the problem is? I am getting the expected behavior when I pass stdout as DEVNULL

```
from subprocess import run, DEVNULL
p = run(['ssh', '-f', 'localhost', 'sleep', '1000'], stdout=DEVNULL)
```

Comment: Just because it's going into the background does not mean it loses its connection to stdout.  You may need to call `subprocess.Popen` to manage this.

Comment: To reiterate the previous comment `run` waits for the subprocess to finish, regardless of whether it's a foreground or background process (in fact this terminology doesn't even make sense here).